# GitHub Gist API patch doesn't work?

Tags: github, github-api, gist

I am creating anonymous Gists using Postman. The Gists get created successfully but when I try to patch them, I get:

```
{
  "message": "Not Found",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#edit-a-gist"
}
```

The URL I am using is:

```
https://api.github.com/gists/14694f43065a32ec28ad
```

If I do a GET, it works fine. If I do a PATCH, I get an error message.

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read and create anonymous gists, but you cannot edit them. If you want to create, read, update and delete, use authentication.

In the [Authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#authentication) section, it says:

> You can read public gists and create them for anonymous users without a token; however, to read or write gists on a user's behalf the **gist** [OAuth scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes) is required.

You will get the same *404–Not found* error if you just try to `git push` some commits into an anonymous gist.

```
$ git push
Username for 'https://gist.github.com': IonicaBizau
Password for 'https://IonicaBizau@gist.github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5801....d2f/' not found
```

They don't even provide an edit button on the Gist page, for anonymous gists. They do have a *Delete* button associated with the IP (any user having the anonymous Gist link, being connected on the same network, assuming they get the same public ip, can delete the anonymous gist).

Otherwise you have to [contact support for deleting](https://help.github.com/articles/deleting-an-anonymous-gist/) the anonymous gist.

Comment: it's a pity that while allowing to delete your anonymous gists in browser (it's not session-based but IP-based) you are not allowed to delete them via API even from the same IP